# How to fix weblogic module exception problem

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, weblogic, weblogic12c

i change my project libs and then weblogic cant deploy my application. i searched about problem and someone said the problem is for conflict local libs and weblogic libs and libraries must be downgraded.
weblogic produces an error like

```
<Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "714909067668592" for task "0".
Error is:"weblogic.application.ModuleException: null
null"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: null
null
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.createModuleException(WebAppModule.java:1824)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:270)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:682)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:98)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:41)
at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.polulateOneClassInfo(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:240)
at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.populateClassInfos(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:193)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

now my question is what library/libraries should be changed to get code to work!
i have these libs[image: list of libraries]

Comment: Can you share the weblogic server's log snippet reporting this exception ?

Comment: Excuse me, did you solve the issue?

Comment: hi @Lazarus, maybe. i don't remember...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. Fixed by downgrading the servlet deployment descriptor from 2.5 to 2.4. You may also try that for a change.
Full link to examples: https://mkyong.com/web-development/the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor-examples/

Herewith your options:

Servlet 3.1 deployment descriptor

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

Servlet 3.0 deployment descriptor

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">
</web-app>
```

Servlet 2.5 deployment descriptor

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
          version="2.5">
</web-app>
```

Servlet 2.4 deployment descriptor

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
          version="2.4">

  <display-name>Servlet 2.4 Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Servlet 2.3 deployment descriptor

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Servlet 2.3 Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```